# Plesk DNS not redirecting

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, email

I need to migrate my email server to a new machine, but the Plesk settings aren't having any effect.

Current setup:

- Windows Server 2003 on ProHosters (VM, holds the current mail server and all the websites)
- Plesk 8.3
- SmarterMail 4.3

New Setup:

- Windows Server 2008 R2 on Steadfast (an actual machine)
- SmarterMail 10.1 (actually working, if I can get the redirect working)

What I'm trying to do is make mail.mydomainname.com on the old machine point to the ip address of the new machine. I went into dns settings in Plesk and set that up, but when I ping it, I still end up at the old one.

I also need to make webmail.mydomainname.com point to port 9998 on the new machine, but that's having the same problem. I have IIS on both machines, if that can help any.

The domains are registered through godaddy, but since the dns server is run by plesk I can't actually change anything in there. I tried adding a host entry, and a subdomain, and neither one made any difference. And I know it's plesk doing the redirecting for webmail, because it says so just before the page switches over.

I'm pretty sure the old machine doesn't have any other DNS control panel, because when we tried to install the standard windows server one, it asked for a cd (and we don't have physical access to it).

P.S.
I know I could send a support ticket to the hosting company, but I'd rather know if I can do this myself for the next time.

Comment: It probably needs to see DNS settings of your registrar and Plesk DNS server to advice here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.

Turns out the DNS settings in Plesk were copied to another machine that took over the job a couple of years ago, so any changes made in there wouldn't have had any effect at all. Unfortunately Plesk itself has no way of knowing that, so it kept the control panel there.